# C# :Programmatically generated emails getting delivered in Junk folder based on Subject line

Tags: c#

I have written a C# program (VS 2015) to generate HTML emails. I have followed programming tips mention here http://www.andreas-kraus.net/blog/tips-for-avoiding-spam-filters-with-systemnetmail/

Emails are delivered in Inbox if I mention the subject text as "Test" or "Survey 2016-17". However, for the same HTML body, emails are landing on Junk E-mail Folder in Outlook if I mention any other subject.

I tried encoding and normalizing my subject text as mentioned below.

```
     message.IsBodyHtml = true;
     message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
     message.Subject.Normalize().Trim();
```

I am sending emails with Normal Priority and the SMTP delivery method is Network. I appreciate any input on this.

Comment: Is the server you're sending these from properly configured with SPF and DKIM? Are you using this code (and having this problem) in a production environment? Or are you only in the dev/test stages? What is the nature of your relationship to the recipients of the email? Are they your own accounts for testing purposes? Or actual end user recipient addresses?

Comment: Hi Bon, I am using this code to send emails to employees within our company. Our server is configured with SPF and DKIM. We have not deployed this code to production due to this problem. Since this is in-house, we tried sending emails to a few actual recipients from dev/test environment.

Comment: Exchange mail server?

Comment: Yes Bon, it is an exchange mail server.

Comment: I am going to further presume these are Outlook mail clients. If so, I think you're doing nothing wrong and I suspect there may be some misconfiguration with their connection to the Exchange server. Couple things could cause this in both the server and the mail client's configurations. If you're able, see if you can replicate this problem with gmail recipients. I predict gmail will receive all your emails, with any subject line.

Comment: You are right Bon. I tried sending programmatically generated emails to my Gmail and Outlook accounts with different subject texts and different HTML body. All emails were delivered in Inboxes of Gmail and Outlook.  I will contact our Exchange Team to fix the misconfiguration issue. Thank you!